# How can i change the RUs dynamically for the containers of cosmos db using the python code or spark?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a large dataset and trying to insert in the cosmos db container and for that i need the increased the throughput. When i use 10000RUs then while inserting data from pyspark, nearly 25000 records in a single dataframe, it works fine. But after that i do not need these high throughput.

So, i want to write a code, by which, before initiating the pipeline, i increase the RUs and after the run is complete for pipeline, i decrease the RUs.

I tried to use azure.cosmos, where the code is available for container dynamic allocation of throughput, but that doesn't work.

```
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
URL = "URL"
KEY = "key"
client = CosmosClient(URL, credential=KEY)

DATABASE_NAME = 'db_name'
database = client.create_database(DATABASE_NAME)
container_name = 'container_name'
container = database.get_container_client(container_name)

for getting the throughputs assigned to the container:
offer = container.read_offer()
for assigning the throughputs assigned to the container:
offer = container.replace_throughput(1500)
```

but still if i check the output for offer, it shows me the same as previous throughput and expected output was 1500 RUs.

Comment: In my experience, reducing throughput is not instantaneous and will take some time. Can you check in portal if the throughput is reduced?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/samples/container_management.py

```
container = db.get_container_client(container=id)   
offer = container.get_throughput()
offer = container.replace_throughput(offer.offer_throughput + 100)
```

Comment: The OP is already calling `container.replace_throughput()`. They haven't shown how they are seeing the original RU/Sec setting, so that would be good for them to clarify in their question, but... seems like they're setting throughput correctly, as written.

Comment: True. I noticed OP was calling read_offer() though. But on reading the docs it seems that like get_throughput() that also returns ThroughputProperties